# Syntax Error in BASH script - readarray + cut command

Tags: arrays, bash, csv, cut

I am trying to parse a comma separated file to a couple arrays.

First array will contain values from the 1st column of the file
Second array will contain values from the 3rd column of the file

I am using readarry and cut to try to accomplish this task, but I am getiing a syntax error:

```
readarray -t VLANs < <( cut -d, -f1 /logs/repository/vlansList.csv )
readarray -t VLANs < <(cut -d, -f1 $1)
```

None of the 2 approaches above are working.

Error is:

```
./ios2NX.sh: line 59: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
./ios2NX.sh: line 59: `         readarray -t VLANs < <( cut -d, -f1 /logs/repository/vlansList.csv)'
```

Funny thing is that the error is not displayed if I test the script with bash - [script_name]

I tried putting the path in quotes and double quotes, the same error was thrown.

Do you guys know what I am missing here or can suggest a better approach than the readarray + cut ?
(lines in my file contain white spaces)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The command looks fine... and the method is fine too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're writing `bash` but running with `sh`.

If your shebang is `#!/bin/sh`, replace it with `#!/bin/bash`

If you're running `sh yourfile`, instead run `bash yourfile`.